# Global variable null when accessed in function run by PHPUnit

Tags: php, command-line, null, phpunit, global-variables

This should be something really simple.

I have the following in `dbconnect.php`:

```
<?php

var_dump($config); // this works! 

function dbconnect($conf = null){
    global $dbconn, $config;

    var_dump($config); // null!

    $config = $conf??$config;
    // A hack to get it working on PHPUnit. For some reason the global variable
    // config is coming in as null

    $dbconn = mysqli_connect(
        $config['dbHost'], $config['dbUser'], $config['dbPass'], $config['dbName']);

    if ($dbconn -> connect_errno) {
      fault("MySQL", "Failed to connect: " . $dbconn -> connect_error);
      exit();
    }   
}

?>
```

As you can see from the comment, `$config` is being accessed as null, even though it's defined in `config.php`:

```
<?php

$config = array();
$config['local']['dbHost'] = 'localhost';
$config['local']['dbName'] = 'logicsmith';
$config['local']['dbUser'] = 'root';
$config['local']['dbPass'] = '*******';

// ... other stuff here

$transferToConfig = ['dbHost', 'dbName', 'dbUser', 'dbPass'];

foreach ($transferToConfig as $name)
    $config[$name] = $config['local'][$name];

// ... other stuff here

?>
```

It only happens when I run via PHPUnit on the command line in Windows (here's the command):

```
php phpunit.phar .\commonTests --testdox --stderr
```

The test file `FaultsTest.php` has the following at the beginning:

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

// ... other stuff here

$configFile = 'C:\wamp2\www\commonTests\includes\config.php';
require 'common/includes/start.php';

// TestCase class here

?>
```

And `start.php` has the following:

```
// ... other stuff here

$configFileToUse = $configFile??__DIR__."/config.php";
require_once($configFileToUse);

// .. other stuff here

require_once(__DIR__."/dbconnect.php");

// ... other stuff here

if (!($bypassDbConnect??''))
{
    dbconnect($config);
    // ... other stuff here
}
```

Bare in mind it works fine when I include `start.php` in a page that I access from WAMP or from my live linux server.

What is going wrong? How do I fix it? I would rather use global variables than having to pass them to every function that needs them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when upgrading PHPUnit. What I discovered is that PHPUnit loads *everything* into a local scope, including the bootstrap file (if used), which used to be a global scope. I had to explicitly define globals in the $GLOBALS superglobal for them to work under PHPUnit. In your case, that means using $GLOBALS["config"] instead of $config in config.php.

Comment: After an upgrade to PHPUnit 10.5 it no longer works with $GLOBALS["config"]. Does anyone have an idea?